# getting php readline extension to work in php 8 xampp installation

Tags: terminal, php, readline, xampp

i have a fresh install of linux mint 21.1 as well as the latest version of xampp which comes with php 8.2.4. i added

`export PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin` to .bashrc
to access php from the terminal. it works and recoginzes the `php` command.

the problem is that i cannot use php interactively with option `php -a`. i get this error instead:

**Interactive shell (-a) requires the readline extension.**

i have only found [this](https://php.watch/versions/8.1/php-a-interactive-readline#enable-readline) discussing the issue and i tried to follow the advice. i installed what i think is the extension with:

`sudo apt install php8.1-readline`

which made this config file: **/etc/php/8.1/mods-available/readline.ini**

i added `'--with-readline'` in **opt/lampp/bin/php-config** to configure_options. (i also tried adding `--with-readline=/etc/php/8.1/mods-available`) but no luck.

i also installed libreadline-dev with `sudo apt install libreadline-dev` as the tutorial i read suggested. but no luck.

is it because php was installed as xampp?

(btw, i restarted apache and opened a new terminal with each try).

UPDATE:

found this in an answer on an old apache forum --

> You cannot add extensions to Xampp. Either it is already included >(what i dont know), or it is not included. You cannot add it, because >you have to recompile the whole thing. As far as it looks, readline is >not part of Xampp.

> If you need readline, you should not use Xampp, instead use the >Packages from Ubuntu (Apache, MySQL, PHP etc.).

i guess i will give up and install them all separate unless someone here knows something... but that was from 2008, so i was hoping something has changed.

Comment: after almost a year from your post, I gave up too